# Writing variables to session from within an Element?

Tags: ajax, cakephp, session-variables

I have an element which is rendered via ajax on my "posts/add" view. The element counts the user's clicks with jQuery and saves it in a variable (let's call it $clickCount).

Now, I would like to pass $clickCount back to the /add view, so I can then save it to the database together with severall other form inputs.

I passed $clickCount to the controller (via Ajax) and tried saving in the session, but it seems like the /add view doesn't see it at all. It's as if the element has a completely different session (which to me makes no sense?). So even though I get the variable passed back to my controller, I can't access it from the posts/add view.

I have spent way too much time on this, I really hope someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it might be because you are making an ajax call to save the session variable, but then you have to remember that you haven't refreshed the page, so the session on the page has not changed, and therefore your new session value isn't available to the view yet.

If you don't want to refresh the page after saving the session value, then you need to return the value back as the response from the ajax request, and add it into your page using JavaScript.  You could write it into a hidden form field or something if that is appropriate for you to save it later into the database.

Or, if possible, save the value to the database when you make the ajax request in the first place, and eliminate the whole session thing (if this won't impact the database).